# mongodb24 homebrew error

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I installed through homebrew the 2.4 version of mongo using the following.

```
brew install homebrew/versions/mongodb24
```

then I tried to start the mongo server using:

```
mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

found in `brew info mongodb24`.

Then I get the following error:

```
error command line: unrecognized line in 'systemLog:'
```

My `mongod.conf` file is the following:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Anyone has encountered the same error? Any ideas how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB 2.4 supports only the "old" configuration file format. YAML configuration files are only supported in [MongoDB 2.6+](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/configuration-options/). Therefore, you need to change your configuration file to use the [old format](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/):

```
logpath=/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logAppend=true

dbPath=/usr/local/var/mongodb
bind_ip=127.0.0.1
```